# How Do I store fence pickets

Tags: wood

We have three remaining 6' by 6" fence pickets that have been treated for termites.  My question is how best to store these?

Comment: ... in a pile? Leaning against a wall? There are endless choices, none of which we could make for you without more information.

Comment: For such things like that I make use of space between joists in the ceiling of the  unfinished basement.

Comment: cut lengthwise into three sections (6'x2") .... cut each of the sections into 4 pieces .... sharpen one end of each piece .... use them for staking vampires

Answer (score 2):

Use them to build a shelf. The treated wood will last forever.

If you don't have any stuff to put on a shelf now, you certainly will soon. After all, you're the kind of person who saves fence pickets.

Comment: They might be specific design fence pickets and easier to store for spares than they might be to find at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a shaded, dry place, with an inch of airspace between them, and between them and other things.

For example, I have some fence slats under my porch.  They are supported by short 2x2 pieces of wood (so that they are 1½" above what is beneath them), and have a gap separating the slats in any given layer of the stack.

You can similarly stack lumber you plan to use, or firewood that you need to dry out.  But make sure that you do not store treated wood with firewood!  You do not want to risk accidentally burning treated wood.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are keeping them as spares and do not want them to be rehabilitated by termites ?

Keep them away form high humidity areas, off the ground and away from moisture.

You can wrap them in a clear bag (termites like the dark) so make it clear perhaps that painters floor spill protection plastic. Seal it up completely with tape. Termites have no trouble with 1/16 inch opening - so make sure you seal it. You can then store it as per my previous information.